# Visual Studio: Warn when private or internal members have no references

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-warnings, private-members

Is there a way to get visual studio to warn that a private member does not have any references within the class? How about internal members that have no references within the package / module?

I have been re-factoring my code and I don't want to keep [right-click] --> Find All References for each member in my code base to ensure I have removed all cruft. There has to be a better way...

Comment: The problem is that private members can legitimately be referenced via Reflection and other ways - consider e.g. binary serialization, or IoC containers.

Comment: Isn't that a very bad code smell if you have to keep private members around because they might be accessed via reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried turning on FxCop performance rules?  They will detect unused members with internal or private access.

Comment: Oooh - nice tool! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Visual Studio does give warnings for unused variables. Doesn't that cover it? They are not errors, just warnings.

Comment: That warning is only on class variables, not methods or properties.

Answer (score 0):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is perfect for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper does something similar with its [Solution-Wide Inspections](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Solution-Wide_Analysis).